# Error to build when update gradle dependency 9.4.0 to 9.6.1

Tags: android, gradle, google-play-services

Hello guys I just update my gradale dependancies but when I build my project it not building.

here is erroe code in grandel console

```
:app:processDebugGoogleServices
Found com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.6.1, but version 9.4.0 is needed for the google-services plugin.
Found com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.1, but version 9.4.0 is needed for the google-services plugin.
Found com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.6.1, but version 9.4.0 is needed for the google-services plugin.
Found com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.6.1, but version 9.4.0 is needed for the google-services plugin.
Found com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.6.1, but version 9.4.0 is needed for the google-services plugin.
:app:processDebugGoogleServices FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 9.4.0.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

here is my app level build gradel look like

```
.
.
.

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
        compile files('libs/commons-codec-1.10.jar')
        compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.0.3@aar'
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.4.0'
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.4.0'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.6.1'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.1'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.6.1'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.6.1'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.6.1'
        compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.3@aar') {
            transitive = true;
        }
    }
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

all my google repository are up to date.
nothing shown in SDK manager to update.

how to fix this

thanks.

Comment: Stop mixing different versions of firebase and google play services.

Comment: Your error mentions you need the latest version of the [Google Services plugin](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're mixing different versions of Firebase and Google Play services. Don't.

```
ext.googlePlayVersion = "9.6.1"
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:$googlePlayVersion"
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-database:$googlePlayVersion"
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:$googlePlayVersion"
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services:$googlePlayVersion"
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:$googlePlayVersion"
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:$googlePlayVersion"
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:$googlePlayVersion"
```

Note: Double quotes are mandatory otherwise the variable will be taken literally.

---

Make sure you're using latest Google services plugin, as of September 26 it's `3.0.0`. Check your *project* `build.gradle`.

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
}
```

Comment: hello it works , firebase just updated their doc here https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/ some time before its 9.4 now its 9.6.0, thanks for you solution